# 2000s(?) anime: a girl uncovers a government secret and can control a phoenix-like monster

Tags: story-identification, anime, soft-sci-fi

All I remember about this anime is a girl and her brother go to a boarding school (I believe) and the girl ends up uncovering a secret.  The government is secretly trying to either destroy or control monsters.

She can control this bird-type monster that looks like a phoenix. A guy, probably an adult, who they met on the boat to their new school controls a dog-/wolf-type monster that might have been mechanical.

I watched this probably about 2009ish.

Comment: So the school controls the dog monster? Or the boat? Ir the adult on the boat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like [Mai-HiME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-HiME). Mai and her younger brother Takumi take a boat trip to their new school, and Mai discovers she can control the phoenix-like Kagutsuchi.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This looks like it might be the right answer; are there details that match other distinctive points in the question, like the guy with the mechanical wolf-monster?